# How to take an array of integer as variable and print out the first element of the array in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am new to kotlin

From what I understanding this code should be working but it isn't

```
fun main(args: Array<Int>) {
   //printing out the first element of the array
    println(args[0])
}

main([12,3,4,5])
```

Comment: It is _arrayOf(12, 3, 4, 5)_ and not _[12,3,4,5]_. It might be worthwhile to study the docs by starting here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html. Regarding arrays the link is: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `main` function is the program entry point and needs to have a specific [function signature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html#program-entry-point).

Also, to create an array in Kotlin from hard-coded elements you would use `arrayOf()`. You can find more about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#arrays).

A working example would be:

```kotlin
fun main()
{
    test(arrayOf(12,3,4,5))
}

fun test(args: Array<Int>) {
    //printing out the first element of the array
    println(args[0])
}
```